# Display a Foreign Key Dropdown in Django Form as Text

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to show a foreign key field in a Django form as an read only text box?

```
forms.py
class NewModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['fk_field', 'other_field']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['fk_field'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True #the dropdown is still active when this is set
        #self.fields['fk_field'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput()) ##when I turn this on, I get an error that I am assigning to the wrong instance.
```

Comment: you can declare the field as class attribute (not in the `__init__()` method) to override it: `fk_field = forms.CharField(required=False, disabled=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can override any of your `ModelForm`'s fields, even those that come from the model, by just setting it as class attribute like you would for a normal `Form` field:

```
class NewModelForm(ModelForm):
    fk_field = forms.CharField(required=False, disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['fk_field', 'other_field']
```

The [`disabled`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) option on a field sets the input to disabled.

Note that you should not trust the data submitted to contain the correct initial value for `fk_field`. Anyone can still submit a different `fk_field` if they know how to use `curl` or Postman, even if the `<input>` is disabled. So if just ignore whatever value is submitted and set it to the correct value in your view.

Comment: Thanks! This worked in connection with updating my view. Because I am using formsets, I had to loop through my instances. This post helped for anybody with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063591/saving-model-before-checking-validity-of-another-formset-for-foreign-key